# Define Dictionary in struct with C#

Tags: c#

I have Struct

```
    struct User
    {
        public int id;
        public Dictionary<int, double> neg;         
    }
    List<User> TempUsers=new List<users>();
    List<User> users = new List<User>();
```

my Problem is, when I run this code

```
TempUsers=users.ToList();
TempUsers[1].neg.Remove(16);
```

neg dictionary in users aslo remove key with value=16

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is because the `Dictionary` is a reference type. You should [clone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78536/deep-cloning-objects) it, for sample:

```
class User : IClonable
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<int, double> Neg { get; set; }

    public object Clone()
    {
        // define a new instance
        var user = new User();

        // copy the properties..
        user.Id = this.Id;    
        user.Neg = this.Neg.ToDictionary(k => k.Key,
                                         v => v.Value);

        return user;
    }
}
```

You shouldn't use a `struct` in a type like this. [In this link, there is a good explanation](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/92339/when-do-you-use-a-struct-instead-of-a-class) about when and how you should use a struct.

Answer (score 2):

Dictionary is a reference type. You should clone you dictionary:
this is an example:

```
    struct User : ICloneable
{
    public int id;
    public Dictionary<int, double> neg;

    public object Clone()
    {
        var user = new User { neg = new Dictionary<int, double>(neg), id = id };
        return user;
    }
}
```